# Installing Visual Studio Code on AWS

Tags: ssh, gui, aws

I have installed Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu server on AWS.

I downloaded the .deb file and followed the instructions to set up as per the following link.

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/setup/linux

The set-up was successful (iAd some trouble with libraries; but was able to resolve them).

As per the instructions code should run by typing "code" on the shell prompt. When I do that on the shell (I connect via ssh), there is no error but nothing seems to happen.

I think this has something to do with GUI display over ssh, but I am not sure what I have to do get this to work.

Comment: Not sure that Amazon allows tunnelling the X server. If it does, you first have to start it on the remote machine and then connect with the `-X` option. Then you can launch any X application and have it running in a Window.

Answer (score 0):

`ssh`, by default, does not allow X11 forwarding (a method of forwarding X11 windows to your computer). To enable it, pass the `-X` option to `ssh`. The SSH server also needs to allow it; make sure the line:

```
X11Forwarding yes
```

is in your server's `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file. If it isn't, add it and restart the SSH daemon:

```
sudo service ssh restart
```

However, some programs, due to the way they draw graphics, don't work at all with X11 forwarding. I haven't tried it with Visual Studio Code before, but I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't work.